# I have upload the excel with the 23k rows in the MYSQL data base it is showing me the error "read ECONNRESET"

Tags: mysql, reactjs, excel, express, sequelize.js

I want to upload the excel data in the Mysql DataBase using the **Sequelize.js technology**. I have use `bulkCreate` to insert the data. **excel has 23k+ rows.**
When I upload the 500 number rows, it will upload smoothly. But when i upload large number of rows, it is throwing me the error

> read ECONNRESET

Here is my code.

```
const db = require("../model");

const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");

const uploadExcel = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.file);
    if (req.file == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send({ msg: "No, Excel File Uploaded" });
    }

    let path = "./ExcelFiles/" + req.file.filename;

    readXlsxFile(path).then((rows) => {
      // skip header
      rows.shift();

      let ExcelArray = [];

      rows.forEach((row) => {
        let excelarray = {
          id: row[0],
          SoldBy: row[1],
          SoldOn: row[2],
          Quantity: row[3],
          NetProfit: row[4],
          District: row[5],
          OverallGP: row[6],
          Dayofthemonth: row[7],
          Type: row[8],
          TotalNewActivations: row[9],
          TotalUpgrades: row[10],
          DeviceName: row[11],
          Accessories: row[12],
          DistrictManager: row[13],
          StoreName: row[14],
        };

        ExcelArray.push(excelarray);
      });
      // Adding the data in the Database Schema

      if (db.ExcelData.findAll()) {
        db.ExcelData.destroy({ where: {} }).then(function () {});
        db.ExcelData.bulkCreate(ExcelArray)
          .then(() => {
            res.status(200).send({
              message:
                "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Fail to import data into database!",
              error: error.message,
            });
          });
      } else {
        db.ExcelData.bulkCreate(ExcelArray)
          .then(() => {
            res.status(200).send({
              message:
                "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.status(500).send({
              message: "Fail to import data into database!",
              error: error.message,
            });
          });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Could not upload the file: " + req.file.originalname,
    });
  }
};

//Get the Data from the Mysql

const GetImport = (req, res) => {
  db.ExcelData.findAll()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials.",
      });
    });
};

module.exports = {
  uploadExcel,
  GetImport,
};
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is in the packets of MySQL Database. The default limit of the mySQL Database packet is 16M in my.ini file.

For the large data, you should put the value 100M.

File location is
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0/my.ini , edit the File and add the

```
max_allowed_packet = 100M
```

it worked for me!

Thanks